# How can I update a ForEach without unnecessary rendering all array of ForEach, working with Binding Element in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of Color, which I am using this array for rendering a View in multiple time, Each element of this array has a State role for a View that works with Binding, So we have an array as array of State, which every single element of that array is going used for feeding a View which needs Binding, the codes working, but every single small update to this array make ForEach render the all array, which is unnecessary, I want to correct or modify my code to stop this unnecessary renders! For example when I change 1 element to Color.black, it is understandable that SwiftUI render a new View for this element but in the fact my codes make SwiftUI render all array! or when I add new element to end of array, the same thing happens! How can I solve this problem? thanks.

*PS: if you think that **index** or **id:.self** make this issue, I have to say No, because I must and I have to use index, because Binding needs an State object, and it is only possible with index, I cannot use item version of ForEach, because Binding cannot update it.*

```
var randomColor: Color { return Color(red: Double.random(in: 0...1), green: Double.random(in: 0...1), blue: Double.random(in: 0...1)) }
```

---

```
struct BindingWay: View {
    
    @State private var arrayOfColor: [Color] = [Color]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ForEach(arrayOfColor.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                
                CircleViewBindingWay(colorOfCircle: $arrayOfColor[index])
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("append new Color") {
                
                arrayOfColor.append(randomColor)
                
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            Button("update last element color to black") {
                
                
                if arrayOfColor.count > 0 {
                    
                    arrayOfColor[arrayOfColor.count - 1] = Color.black
                    
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            

        }
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CircleViewBindingWay: View {
    
    @Binding var colorOfCircle: Color
    
    init(colorOfCircle: Binding<Color>) { print("initializing CircleView"); _colorOfCircle = colorOfCircle }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        print("rendering CircleView")
        
        return Circle()
            .fill(colorOfCircle)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .onTapGesture { colorOfCircle = colorOfCircle.opacity(0.5) }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
struct CircleViewBindingWay: View {
    
    @Binding var colorOfCircle: Color
    
    init(colorOfCircle: Binding<Color>) { print("initializing CircleView"); _colorOfCircle = colorOfCircle }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        print("rendering CircleView")
        
        return Circle()
            .fill(colorOfCircle)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .onTapGesture { colorOfCircle = colorOfCircle.opacity(0.5) }
    }
}

extension CircleViewBindingWay : Equatable { //<-- here
    static func == (lhs: CircleViewBindingWay, rhs: CircleViewBindingWay) -> Bool {
        lhs.colorOfCircle == rhs.colorOfCircle
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var arrayOfColor: [Color] = [Color]()
    
    var randomColor: Color { return Color(red: Double.random(in: 0...1), green: Double.random(in: 0...1), blue: Double.random(in: 0...1)) }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(arrayOfColor.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                CircleViewBindingWay(colorOfCircle: .init(get: { () -> Color in //<-- here
                    arrayOfColor[index]
                }, set: { (newValue) in
                    arrayOfColor[index] = newValue
                }))
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("append new Color") {
                arrayOfColor.append(randomColor)
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            Button("update last element color to black") {
                if arrayOfColor.count > 0 {
                    arrayOfColor[arrayOfColor.count - 1] = Color.black
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}
```

What has to happen:

1. `CircleViewBindingWay` conforms to `Equatable` and checks that the colors are the same. `ForEach` does the equatable check itself, which is why actually attaching `.equatable()` isn't necessary
2. The `Binding` is declared inline. There must be another equatable check that `ForEach`/`SwiftUI` does on the `$arrayOfColor` that fails, but this inline one passes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am really confused, I cannot understand and follow your way, and what is happening, also not big fan of using Binding.init()

Comment: What are you confused by?

Comment: I am mostly confused by using **==** and **Binding.init()**, I want learn and teach my self with asking about the issue, I do not need really fix this code or something, I want get the idea of solving, that i cannot get right now, and confused

Comment: == is what gets used by `Equatable`. Here's a good resource on that: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-equatable-protocol

Comment: Binding.init() allows you to create a dynamic binding where you get to control the get/set behavior rather than the system doing it for you (which doesn't give you any flexibility)

Comment: I know the Equatable topic, but I cannot find connection between that and this issue.

Comment: I just accept the answer because solve the issue, but I really did not understand the answer. thanks for your time.

Comment: Equatable is very applicable here because the system uses it to determine whether or not to re-render the element. It's the key to a lot of SwiftUI performance.

Comment: thanks again, for information and your time.

Comment: @swiftPunk To elaborate on what jnpdx is saying, SwiftUI rerenders a view any time something changes. By making your custom Type conform to Equatable, it Is giving SwiftUI a way to know exactly when something has changed or when it hasnt. 

Hope that helps make it clear

Comment: @SergioBost: thanks, my goal is understanding what is happing, not getting code for copy and paste, I know all about Equatable or Binding, my issue is not those, Which part is going use **==** function? ForEach or Binding or customView?

Comment: @swiftPunk == is what `Equatable` uses to tell whether to things are equal. The system compares the two elements, using that function. `ForEach` calls this on the `CircleViewBindingWay` to compare them and see if the need to be re-rendered.

Comment: @swiftPunk ForEach will use the == to see when to reprender view

Comment: @jnpdx: thanks, it is funny and sad for that I cannot wire all that information in my mind to understand the puzzle, I am too dum for this issue.

Comment: Well, I'm not confident that I understand exactly when and how SwiftUI uses equatable. Here's a good resource: https://swiftui-lab.com/equatableview/

Comment: @jnpdx I cannot find anywhere where ForEach calls this method either but only by the process of elimination one can assume.. ForEach is responsible for the rendering of each element. Anyway , thanks for the deep dive on this, I’ll be reading that article some time soon